# How to avoid null fatal error when user its logged out | Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, user-interface, authentication, logical-operators

The app that I am building has a feature where the logged in user has the chance to drag n'drop pictures to upload to the server.

The thing is that when the user its not logged in I want the upload section to be hidden on the view.  Here is my logic on upload view:

```
 @if($user->owns($post))
         <hr>
         <h2>Add Your Photos</h2>
         <form action="{{route('store_photo_path', [$post->slug, $post->location])}}" class="dropzone" id="addPhotosForm">

         {{csrf_field()}}

         </form>
@endif
```

As u can see I wrote the logic to see if the user its logged in, but its giving me the error `Call to a member function owns() on null`

Note: owns() its a method created on the User model.

```
public function owns($relation){

    return $relation->user_id=$this->id;

 }
```

Note $relation var its the post object that its available on the view and it is being sent to the function to check if the user who has created the post is same  as logged in user.

I am trying to check if we have any logged in user and if so with `owns()` method i am checking to see if the logged in user is the owner of the post itself. But when I have no users logged in I get the null error ?!

Maybe my approach is wrong any suggestion ?!

P.s $user its a global blade view variable initialized on my `boot()` method on AppServiceProvider like so;

```
public function boot()
{
    //
     Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

    //return authenticated user to all views
    \View::composer('*', function($view){
    $view->with('user', \Auth::user());
});
```

Comment: How do you check a user logged in or not? By the way you can add a @ simbol to  if in view like this `@if(@$user->owns($post))` to avoid null error.

Comment: yes I can add that @if condition, but when user its not logged in User model its not even initialized furthermore $user will be null in that case. I check to see if the user its authenticated through $user variable that is made global on my app service provider. check the edited post.

Comment: For this situation you on it i think you can make a global function to check it for you to is this post belongs to auth user or not.

Comment: This functionality is something that gates and policies provides. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved: Check if the user exists and has a post.

```
 @if($user && $user->owns($post))
         <hr>
         <h2>Add Your Photos</h2>
         <form action="{{route('store_photo_path', [$post->slug, $post->location])}}" class="dropzone" id="addPhotosForm">

         {{csrf_field()}}

         </form>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The `owns` checks if logged in user owns the post.  It doesn't check if the user is logged in. 
You could do this:

```
@if(Auth::check() && $user->owns($post)) 
    <hr> 
    <h2>Add Your Photos</h2>
    <form action="{{route('store_photo_path', [$post->slug, $post->location])}}" class="dropzone" id="addPhotosForm"> {{csrf_field()}} </form> 
@endif
```

Hope it helps